# Why in android studio 'add library dependency' option take too much time when we add any new dependency?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using the latest version of the android studio and whenever we add new library dependency from the 'add new dependency' option it takes too much time. and it shows a different kind of dependency in option but not the original one which I want to use in my project

In my project, I want to use 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'but this option not showing in 'add new dependency' option

I am also sharing a screenshot for a better understanding.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5cNz.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way to add library is:

1. Open the `build.gradle(Module: app)` in `Android Studio`.
2. Add your library with `implementation` at beginning, in the `dependencies`, like this:

   ```
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
   ```

And then click on Sync Now, to add the library to your project:

[image]

If it takes a long time but your project does not sync, check your internet connection or use VPN.